# Show required asterisk star after the text?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to show `asterisk red star` after the text, but text has width which does not allow to insert the asterisk after the text. See below example

### code

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 required-field">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactPhoneNumber, new { @class = "control-label-nobold" })
</div>
```

### Generate Html

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 required-field">
  <label class="control-label-nobold" for="ContactPhoneNumber">If you wish to be contacted by phone, enter your phone number</label>
</div>
```

### css

```
.required-field:after {
    content: "*";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

### page

Star showing next line

[image]

Text has width which is not allowing me to add asterisk

[image]

How can I add star next to text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the :after to the label.

```
.required-field .control-label-nobold:after {
content: "*";
font-weight: bold;
color: red;
}
```

Update: Sorry, missed the .required-field class.

Comment: One could also use `.required-field label:after`, if that's more appropriate for general use.

Answer (score 0):

With this method you can show required asterisk star after the text.

HTML:

`<label>Title<span>*</span></label>`

Code:
$('label span').css('color', 'red');